# How would I break on "optimization opportunities in xcode/lldb?

Tags: xcode, lldb

I get a suggestion from xcode machinery regarding swapping CAShapeLayer for a CALayer due
to a simple shape with rounded corners.

> x-xcode-debug-views://7f93b7c5d6b0?DBGViewDebuggerLaunchSessionParameter=7f93b7c5d6b0
> A `CAShapeLayer` is used with a path that's a rect, a rounded-rect, or
> an ellipse. Instead, use an appropriately transformed plain CALayer
> with `cornerRadius` set.

How could I find the offending object for that suggestion?
There must be a WWDC session for this ;^)